Pysnmp 7.0.3 Bulk walk Agent MIB Returning additional Data
When following the SNMPv2c example found here https://docs.lextudio.com/pysnmp/examples/v1arch/asyncio/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations
I am seeing additional returned information which I haven't requested as part of the SNMPBulkWalk.
For example when running "snmpbulkwalk -v2c -c   1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2 from linux CLI I receive a list of all interface names of the device I am querying.
:~ $ snmpbulkwalk -v2c -c SNMPubliV2c 10.180.0.8 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 = STRING: "lo"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 = STRING: "eth3"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.3 = STRING: "eth0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.4 = STRING: "eth1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.5 = STRING: "eth2"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.6 = STRING: "npi0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.7 = STRING: "npi1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.8 = STRING: "npi2"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.9 = STRING: "npi3"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10 = STRING: "loop0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.11 = STRING: "loop1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.12 = STRING: "loop2"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.13 = STRING: "loop3"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.14 = STRING: "imq0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.15 = STRING: "eth1.130"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.17 = STRING: "pppoe0"


Where as when I run the example code but with my   and 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2. I seem to get a whole bunch of additional data. I have copy a section of it here but there is way more being spewed out to console.
...
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.12 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.13 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.14 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.15 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.16 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.17 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.10.18 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.1 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.2 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.3 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.4 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.5 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.6 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.7 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.8 - 0
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.15.1.1.11.9 - 0
...

I have found if I put an exit(0) above the return wholeMsg from the SNMPv2c example. It prints only the requested information to the terminal. But then of cause the script stops...
I am pretty new to all of this and stepping through the code with print statements I couldn't really identify how additional mibs are being returned when I have only specified one value in headVars.
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncio.dispatch import AsyncioDispatcher
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncio.dgram import udp
from pyasn1.codec.ber import encoder, decoder
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c

# SNMP table header
headVars = [v2c.ObjectIdentifier((1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,2))]

# Build PDU
reqPDU = v2c.GetBulkRequestPDU()
v2c.apiBulkPDU.setDefaults(reqPDU)
v2c.apiBulkPDU.setNonRepeaters(reqPDU, 0)
v2c.apiBulkPDU.setMaxRepetitions(reqPDU, 25)
v2c.apiBulkPDU.setVarBinds(reqPDU, [(x, v2c.null) for x in headVars])

# Build message
reqMsg = v2c.Message()
v2c.apiMessage.setDefaults(reqMsg)
v2c.apiMessage.setCommunity(reqMsg, "<COMMUNITY")
v2c.apiMessage.setPDU(reqMsg, reqPDU)


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def cbRecvFun(
    transportDispatcher,
    transportDomain,
    transportAddress,
    wholeMsg,
    reqPDU=reqPDU,
    headVars=headVars,
):
    while wholeMsg:
        rspMsg, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(wholeMsg, asn1Spec=v2c.Message())

        rspPDU = v2c.apiMessage.getPDU(rspMsg)

        # Match response to request
        if v2c.apiBulkPDU.getRequestID(reqPDU) == v2c.apiBulkPDU.getRequestID(rspPDU):
            # Format var-binds table
            varBindTable = v2c.apiBulkPDU.getVarBindTable(reqPDU, rspPDU)

            # Check for SNMP errors reported
            errorStatus = v2c.apiBulkPDU.getErrorStatus(rspPDU)
            if errorStatus and errorStatus != 2:
                errorIndex = v2c.apiBulkPDU.getErrorIndex(rspPDU)
                print(
                    "{} at {}".format(
                        errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBindTable[int(errorIndex) - 1] or "?",
                    )
                )
                transportDispatcher.jobFinished(1)
                break

            # Report SNMP table
            for tableRow in varBindTable:
                for name, val in tableRow:
                    print(f'{name} - {val}')

            # Stop on EOM
            for oid, val in varBindTable[-1]:
                if not isinstance(val, v2c.Null):
                    break

            else:
                transportDispatcher.jobFinished(1)
                continue

            # Generate request for next row
            v2c.apiBulkPDU.setVarBinds(
                reqPDU, [(x, v2c.null) for x, y in varBindTable[-1]]
            )

            v2c.apiBulkPDU.setRequestID(reqPDU, v2c.getNextRequestID())

            transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
                encoder.encode(reqMsg), transportDomain, transportAddress
            )
    # <-----Placing exit(0) here prints only the MIBS I am looking for.
    return wholeMsg


transportDispatcher = AsyncioDispatcher()

transportDispatcher.registerRecvCbFun(cbRecvFun)

transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
    udp.DOMAIN_NAME, udp.UdpAsyncioTransport().openClientMode()
)

transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
    encoder.encode(reqMsg), udp.DOMAIN_NAME, ("<IPADDRESS>", 161)
)

transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

# Dispatcher will finish as job#1 counter reaches zero
transportDispatcher.runDispatcher(3)

transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

It looks like this library went though a period of not being managed and is now once again being managed but a lot has changed and other stackoverflow records either aren't relevant anymore or point of links which dont exist.
Any help would really be appreciated as I want to learn but I am very stumped.

This is simply because the sample script is designed to perform a complete WALK defined in IETF RFC to discover every following objects, while Net-SNMP snmpbulkwalk command performs a partial WALK and discovers only objects within the subtree of your input OID.
Nothing is wrong here, and the behavior is consistent from 4.x to 7.x.

Thanks Lex Li for the response. Does this mean I am going about this the wrong way? Is there a different way or method I should be using to only collect the information I require? Sounds like I am doing something inefficiently.
Any guidance would be appreciated.
Also aren't you the new support man for pysnmp... really cool you replied. :)

@Theyouth1 this is part of the community support offering https://www.pysnmp.com/support.html. You have to figure out what you really want, a partial WALK or a complete one, and then dig further into previous discussions to better understand how to revise the code. Ilya answered such topics a few years ago.

Thanks for the clarification on the terms I should use. I will do some more research and get to the bottom of what I am trying to achieve.
